# Line to Line or Line to Neutral voltage to calculate 3 phase power

Tags: power, three-phase

I am confused as to whether or not I should use the line to line voltage on a 3 phase motor or the line to neutral voltage to calculate power? Would someone please be able to fill me in, and possibly offer an explanation as to why? I do believe there are explanations explaining how the L-L and L-N voltages are related, but I need to know which one is used to calculate power. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how the load is connected.  Take the voltage that appears across the load, whether L-L or L-N.  It may help to imagine a resistive heater first, understand that, then translate to a motor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both voltages to calculate power, but it yields to a different expression. If \$U_f\$ is the line to neutral voltage and \$i_L\$ the current in one the lines, then:

$$P=3U_fi_L\cos \phi$$

Now because line to line voltage \$U_L\$ is related to \$U_f\$ by \$U_L=\sqrt 3 U_f\$, then after substituting in the previous expression we have:

$$P=\sqrt 3U_Li_L\cos \phi$$

Answer (score 0):

S [VA] = I<sub>line</sub> × V<sub>line-line</sub> × √3.

Note `S` is 'apparent power', which has units of volt-amps. This is a different quantity to `P`, which has units of watts. `S` and `P` are related by the power factor.

Comment: If you're going to give a mathematical answer, you need to define your terms. What is `S[VA]`?

Comment: See above. Not much of an answer anyway; I had intended to add a diagram but didn't get time.